# Regular expression case insensitive match

Tags: regex

How to making a regular expression to search string as case insensitive ? example, I've a regular expression as below which it can matched the string dell but it cant match if the string is Dell or DELL and etc..
I've searched some example on net by using flag i, but it doesn't worked, and I don't want to rewrite the pattern as `.*[Dd][Ee][Ll][Ll].*` because the string could be variable. I testing this pattern in http://www.regexr.com/

```
.*(dell).*
```

Comment: In which language? Also provide an test string please...

Comment: What doesn't work with `i` flag?

Comment: My mistake, actually i forgot turn on i flag

Comment: problem solved, please close this post

Answer (score 0):

Use the i modifier:

```
/\W(dell)\W/i
```

Comment: Thank for your replied